# Como usar uma variável já existente como contador

Tags: java, if, for, scanner

O meu objetivo é pegar a letra do alfabeto que o usuário digitou e mostrar, quantas forem as vezes que ele digitar, as letras antecessoras e sucessoras dessa, entende?
Olha o que eu fiz:

```
static int v;
static String[] Alfa = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L",
        "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"};

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String letra;
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Digite uma letra: ");
    letra = s.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Quantas letras deseja mostrar?");
    v = s.nextInt();

    for(int i = 1; i < Alfa.length; i++) {
        if(letra == Alfa[i]) {
            for(int i; i <= 1;) {
                System.out.print(Alfa[i--] + " ");
            }

            System.out.print(Alfa[i]);

            for(int i; i <= v;) {
                System.out.print(" " + Alfa[i++]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Acontece que eu tenho que usar o valor do Alfa[i] que está dentro do if nos for's, mas como eu faço isso?

Comment: faz um `for` fora pra descobrir em qual posição do vetor tá a letra q ele digitou, dps um `for` `v vezes` mostrando `i++` e `i--`

Answer (score 2):

Talvez seja interessante fazer um tratamento de erro para caso o usuário entre com um válor que vá ultrapassar o tamanho da String, por exemplo escolher a letra Y e mostrar 20 elementos. Não fiz isso pois não foi mencionado. Em geral ficaria assim:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String letra;
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Digite uma letra: ");
    letra = s.nextLine();
    System.out.println(letra);
    System.out.print("Quantas letras deseja mostrar?");
    v = s.nextInt();

    for(int i = 0; i < Alfa.length; i++) {
        if(letra.equals(Alfa[i])) {
            for(int j = v; j > 0; j--) {
                System.out.print(Alfa[i-j] + " ");

            }

            System.out.print(Alfa[i]);

            for(int j = 1; j <= v; j++) {
                System.out.print(" " + Alfa[i+j]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Exemplo de entrada:

```
D
2
```

Saída:

```
B C D E F
```

Answer (score 0):

Conforme sugeri no comentário:

```
static int v;
static String[] Alfa = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L",
        "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"};

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String letra;
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Digite uma letra: ");
    letra = s.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Quantas letras deseja mostrar?");
    v = s.nextInt();

    for(int i = 0; i < Alfa.length; i++) {
        if(letra == Alfa[i]) {
            break;
        }
    }

    for(int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
        if (i+j < Alfa.length) {
            System.out.print(Alfa[i+j] + " ");
        }
        if (i-j >= 0) {
            System.out.print(Alfa[i-j] + " ");
        }
    }
}
```